# Lost The binding MVVM silverlight 5

Tags: c#, mvvm, silverlight-5.0

When I was making an adjustment to a project, I run the application and find that 2 comboboxes are not binded

```
        <ComboBox x:Name="ComboAgente" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center"
              Height="23" Grid.Row="2" 
              Grid.Column="2" 
              Margin="10,0,0,0" 
              MinWidth="200"
              IsEnabled="{Binding Path=ModoLectura, Converter={StaticResource NotOperatorValueConverter}}" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Transmisores}" DisplayMemberPath="NombreAgenteConcepto" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=AgenteSeleccionado,Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}" Width="226" />
```

in the view models prop...

```
        public List<TransmisorNacionalTO> Transmisores
    {
        get
        {
            return transmisorescargados;
        }
        set
        {
            if (transmisorescargados != value)
            {
                transmisorescargados = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Transmisores);
            }
        }
    }

    public TransmisorNacionalTO AgenteSeleccionado
    {
        get
        {
            return agenteseleccionado;
        }
        set
        {
            agenteseleccionado = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.AgenteSeleccionado);
        }
    }
```

Combobox #2

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ComboConvocatoria" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="23" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="2" 
              Margin="10,0,0,0" MinWidth="200" 
              IsEnabled="{Binding Path=ModoLectura, Converter={StaticResource NotOperatorValueConverter}}" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Convocatorias}" DisplayMemberPath="Nombre" 
              SelectedItem="{Binding Path=ConvocatoriaSeleccionada,Mode=TwoWay, ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True}" Width="225" />
```

propieties

```
    public List<ConvocatoriaTO> Convocatorias
    {
        get
        {
            return convocatorias;
        }
        set
        {
            if (convocatorias != value)
            {
                convocatorias = value;
                this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Convocatorias);
            }
        }
    }


    public ConvocatoriaTO ConvocatoriaSeleccionada
    {
        get
        {
            return convocatoriaSeleccionada;
        }
        set
        {
            convocatoriaSeleccionada = value;
            this.RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.ConvocatoriaSeleccionada);
        }
    }
```

There are 2 properties defined in the ViewModel, for each comboboxes first one; Transmisores which is a List and the AgenteSeleccionado property which is a object of TransmisorNacionalTO

The second one is the propriety for ConvocatoriaSeleccionada is a Object, and Convocatorias is the list

I don't think I deleted any piece of code!

Comment: Don't know what changed but should use ObservableCollection for the bound data source.  ObservableCollection fires PropertyChanged when items are removed from the list.  What you have would only change the list if you create a brand new List